# Moving specific number (without sort) to the left of list

Tags: python, list

I want to just move the zero's to left and don't want to sort the list.

For example, if my list is like:

```
nums = [1, 10, 20, 0, 59, 63, 0, 8, 0]
```

Here's the output which I desire after moving all the Zero's to left:

```
output = [0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 20, 59, 63, 8]
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
class Solution:
    def moveZeroes(self, nums):
        c = 0
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] != 0:
                nums[i], nums[c] = nums[c], nums[i]
                c += 1
        return nums
print(Solution().moveZeroes(nums))
```

This code gives me output as:

```
 [1, 10, 20, 59, 63, 8, 0, 0, 0]
```

But my desired output is:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 20, 59, 63, 8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
output = []
for i in nums:
    if i == 0:
        output.insert(0, 0)
    else:
        output.append(i)
output
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with *key* as [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) to achieve this as:

```
>>> nums = [1, 10, 20, 0, 59, 63, 0, 8, 0]

>>> sorted(nums, key=bool)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 20, 59, 63, 8]
```

It will work for `0`s. In order **to make it more generic for any number**, you can define *key* as `lambda x: x!=left_num`:

```
>>> left_num = 0

>>> sorted(nums, key=lambda x: x!=left_num)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 20, 59, 63, 8]
```

---

As an alternative, here's a less *Pythonic* (but efficient) version of it using [`list.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> nums = [1, 10, 20, 0, 59, 63, 0, 8, 0]
>>> left_num = 0

>>> [left_num]*nums.count(left_num) + [n for n in nums if n!=left_num]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 20, 59, 63, 8]
```

Here I am finding the count of zeroes in the list (say `n`), and assigning `n` zeroes in the start of new list. To get the rest of the unsorted list, I am using *list comprehension* to filter out the `0`s from the list.

Answer (score 4):

```
sorted(nums, key=lambda i: i != 0)
# or
sorted(nums, key=bool)
```

Comment: Or `sorted(nums, key=bool)`

Comment: @SayandipDutta yes, you are right, will update the answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could filter out the zeros and insert the number of removed zeros at the begining of the output list:

```
nums   = [1, 10, 20, 0, 59, 63, 0, 8, 0]

output = list(filter(None,nums))
output = [0]*(len(nums)-len(output)) + output

print(output)
# [0, 0, 0, 1, 10, 20, 59, 63, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

since the question does not mention any constraints, maybe this fine piece of one-line will help you:

```
def zero_left(list):
     return [x for x in list if x == 0] + [x for x in list if x!=0]
```